# Connect to a wireless network as standard user without administrator authentication Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, authentication

I'm trying to get a standard user on my laptop installed with Linux Mint 17.3 on the wireless. I can get to the internet just fine logged in with an administrator but as soon as i log in with a standard user it asks to unlock a system setting then asks for the password for the wireless again despite my having saved it. Since anyone that uses this laptop besides me will be using the standard account, they won't have any passwords this makes it unusable for any purposes that require an internet connection.

Relevant attempts to fix: 1.Adding the standard user to the netdev group - no change 2.Adding a new/second admin account - no change 3.Looked up a tutorial on the Linux Mint site titled "Connect to a wireless network as standard user without administrator authentication" - this page was completely blank

Note: It is definitely not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the wireless settings to enable access for all users.

1. Log in as an admin
2. In the panel, click on the network icon, and select network connections.
3. Select the network you want to enable for all users, and click Edit.
4. In the "General" section, check the option for "All users may connect to this network" and optionally check the "Automatically connect to this network" option as well.

Hopefully, this will solve the problem.

Comment: No change. I think i've tried this before as well.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below remove-sudo-password-when-connecting-to-new-wifi-network

[image: remove-sudo-password-when-connecting-to-new-wifi-network]

Comment: Posting text as images is highly discouraged—some users may not be able to see the answer